# Port Forwarding to OpenVPN connects once then stops connecting

Tags: iptables, smtp, openvpn, port-forwarding, imap

I am attempting to forward the IMAP and SMTP ports from a external IP address (x.x.x.x) to a computer on a private network via an OpenVPN connection (10.8.0.100). I currently have an OpenVPN server (10.8.0.1) that exists on the same machine with the external IP (x.x.x.x).

I forwarded ports 993, 587 and 143 using iptables from x.x.x.x to 10.8.0.100, and I can connect via telnet to any of those ports externally and get a response from the the internal IMAP and SMTP servers, but once I close the connection, I cannot reconnect for an amount of time (something like ~30 secs). If I try to connect immediately, it just hangs there saying, "Trying x.x.x.x..." and won't connect. If I stop trying for an amount of time, and try again, it responds fine again. But if I close the connection, it happens again.

This also also happens if I am on the machine with the OpenVPN server itself. If I telnet into 10.8.0.100 on port 143, let's say, it will connect and then if I close the connection and try again, it sits there.

```
root@x.x.x.x:~# telnet 10.8.0.100 143
Trying 10.8.0.100...
Connected to 10.8.0.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
d
d BAD Error in IMAP command received by server.
d
d BAD Error in IMAP command received by server.
d
* BYE Too many invalid IMAP commands.
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@x.x.x.x:~# telnet 10.8.0.100 143
Trying 10.8.0.100...
```

Now if I go onto a computer in the private network where the IMAP/SMTP servers are at, I can telnet to those ports no problem, close them and reopen as quickly as I want.

I have been searching for a few days now on a way to attempt to remedy this, but I can't seem to find anything on the web related to this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
Adding iptables-save output:

```
~# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Sep 19 00:13:24 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [7476:440381]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6361:381728]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5842:414754]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [5829:413974]
-A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.100:993
-A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.100:587
-A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.100:143
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1:993
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1:587
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1:143
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 19 00:13:24 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Sep 19 00:13:24 2015
*filter
:INPUT DROP [42:2113]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 993 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 587 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 143 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d y.y.y.y/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d z.z.z.z/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 30/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-forward -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-forward -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED:** I decided to start with clean set of iptables rules doing the following:

```
iptables -F
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables -F (maybe not necessary but did it at the end anyhow)
```

I decided to disable ufw and use iptables to allow udp on port 1194 (OpenVPN port).

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

Then using https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76300/iptables-port-to-another-ip-port-from-the-inside as my guide, I did the following:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 143 -d x.x.x.x -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 143 -d 10.8.0.100 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 143 -d 10.8.0.100 -j ACCEPT
```

Now, I can telnet into port 143, close the connection and immediate reopen the connection without having to wait. I did this for all IMAP(S) and SMTP(S) ports.